# Trouble with jquery load on Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, load

I'm creating a demo that must be in html code only (no server side code such as PHP, etc). I'd like to use jquery and the .load function to call in some content dynamically. This is working fine in Firefox, but for some reason the page I want to get is not loading in Chrome (v 5.0).

The code I am using is very simple:

```
  $("div#contentarea").load("ajax/page.html");
```

and yet the contents of page.html do not load. I've tried putting standard HTML header tags in (`<html>, <head>, <body>`, etc) and also leaving them out (leaving them out usually works best) of the page.html file.

Because this works in Firefox, I am not seeing any error messages in Firebug.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does `page.html` output? Can you show a sample? Are you 1000% sure there are no other elements with the id `contentarea`?

Comment: Is this on a server or on the local filesystem?

Comment: "Because this works in Firefox, I am not seeing any error messages in Firebug." - Chrome also has a Firebug-like console. Once you're used to it, it covers the 80% of what people use Firebug for quite easily. CTRL+SHIFT+J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of a [bug fix](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=4197) in Chrome.

Run Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option to fix this problem.  Or, move your code on a Web server (instead of using `file://`).

Comment: Can I ask how I would enable this option in Chrome? Do I add this to the executable command line?

Answer (score 1):

As Strager said, adding --allow-file-access-from-files to a Chrome shortcut solves this issue. I also found that by also adding --relauncher, you don't need to close your open chrome windows for this to work. this was a huge thing for me!

Glad I got it to work. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good read.
http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/msg/14925da1b4540acd?pli=1

May or may not help

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I found the .get function works well. I don't need to run Chrome with any special flags.

```
$.get(_url, pars, function(data) {
     $( '#ajaxReplaceMe' ).html( data );
});
```

Where ajaxReplaceMe is the id of the (say) div element where you want the content to load.